# ExpandableListView Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I trying to populate an expandablelistview, with data from a database that is populated my a httprequest. So far I have been able to populate the database without any problems. I get NullPointerException error when I try to set the adapter of the expandablelistview. Another thing I have to think about is before I can set the adapter I have to execute a thread that will check my online database to see if it is the some version/uptodate with my phone database.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private List<lvItem> myLVItems = new ArrayList<lvItem>();
    private List<Parent> myParent = new ArrayList<Parent>();
    ExpandableListView exv;
    final DBHelper db2 = new DBHelper(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        exv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                ButtonClick(v);
            }
        });


         db2.open();

         dbVersion dbversion = new dbVersion();
         dbversion.checkDBVersion(db2, myParent, myLVItems);

    }

    public void ButtonClick(View v)
    {

    }
}
```

dbVersion.java

```
public class dbVersion 
{

    DBHelper db2;
    List<Parent> parent;
    List<lvItem> myLVItems;
    ExpandableListView exv;
    Context context;

    public void checkDBVersion(DBHelper db, List<Parent> myParent, List<lvItem> mylvitems, ExpandableListView exv2, Context context2) 
    {
        this.db2 = db;
        this.parent = myParent;
        this.myLVItems = mylvitems;
        this.context = context2;
        this.exv = exv2;

        VerCheckThread vercheckthread = new VerCheckThread();
        vercheckthread.execute();

    }

    public class VerCheckThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
             //This populates my database
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
             checkdbs(result); //result is current db version
        }
    }

    public void checkdbs(String line) 
    {

        Cursor c = db2.getAllVersionRecords();

        if(c.getCount()<1)
        {
            Log.i("dbVersion, checkdbs", "There is not an entry for the table version");       
            VerCreateThread vercreatetheard = new VerCreateThread();
            vercreatetheard.execute();
        }
        else
        {
            c.moveToLast();
            String lastid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
            lastid.trim();
            line.trim();
            if(lastid.equals(line))
            {
                Log.i("dbVersion, checkdbs", "DBs are up-to-date");             

                lvl2 l2 = new lvl2();
                lvl3 l3 = new lvl3();

                l3.popLvl3(db2,myLVItems); //this populates myLVItems
                l2.popLvl2List(db2,parent); //this populates parent

                Log.i("dbVersion, checkdbs", "myLVItems size = "+myLVItems.size()); //checking the size of myLVItems to see if they were populated
                Log.i("dbVersion, checkdbs", "parent size = "+parent.size()); //checking the size of parent to see if they were populated

                exv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(context)); //this is causing the error
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("dbVersion, checkdbs", "DBs NOT utd phonedb = "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"))+ " webdb = "+ line);

                db2.updateDB();
                VerCreateThread vercreatetheard = new VerCreateThread();
                vercreatetheard.execute();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    List<Parent> parent;
    private List myLVItems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    String []groupList = {"Subject One","Subject Two","Subject Three"}; // for now this is to populate the group

    public MyAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,ViewGroup parentView) 
    {
        final Parent parent;
        lvItem currentLVItem = (lvItem) myLVItems.get(childPosition);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.db_items, parentView, false);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageResource(currentLVItem.getIconId());

        TextView hiddenView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subIdtextView);
        hiddenView.setText(currentLVItem.getId());

        TextView summaryView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subSubjectTextView);
        summaryView.setText(currentLVItem.getSummary());

        TextView descripView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subScriptTextView2);
        descripView.setText(currentLVItem.getScripts());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
    {
        return childList[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int arg0) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() 
    {
        return groupList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(groupList[groupPosition]);

        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() 
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) 
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

LogCat:

```
01-07 21:20:48.141: I/dbVersion, checkdbs(1715): myLVItems size = 18
01-07 21:20:48.141: I/dbVersion, checkdbs(1715): parent size = 4
01-07 21:20:48.141: D/AndroidRuntime(1715): Shutting down VM
01-07 21:20:48.152: W/dalvikvm(1715): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb5cba908)
01-07 21:20:48.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 21:20:48.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1715): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 21:20:48.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at com.example.project.dbVersion.checkdbs(dbVersion.java:132)
```

Comment: 1. Is exv null? 2. You have `setAdapter` in VerCheckThread's onPostExecute() commented out. This seems like the right strategy. Setting the adapter after a button click does not seem like a good idea, since you don't know if the background thread is finished.

Comment: @MikeOrtiz Thank you for your response. 1. Yes, I guess, since exv will not be inflated until MyAdapter is called. 2. That was my first thought and then I started moving it around to try and get it to work. Should I pass "exv" and "this" to dbVersion... dbversion.checkDBVersion(db2, myParent, myLVItems, exv, this); I've tried doing it this way and I was still getting an error.

Comment: 1. It should not be null after calling `findViewById` at the point when you set the adapter. That would obviously be the cause of the NPE as it means the ListView was not found in xml. 2. What was the error?

Comment: I edited my post to place exv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(context)); in dbVersion.java, and I also added the LogCat that has some useful info. Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: Add this line: `if (exv == null) Log.d("debug", "Expandable list is null!");` after the line `exv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);`. I'm pretty sure your expendable list view is null. It could be because you have the wrong id name. OR, you might want to move `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` to the top of the `onCreate` method. It might be causing troubles that you call `findViewById` before creating the Activity.

Comment: @MikeOrtiz moving the super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); to the top worked. Put that as the answer so i can give you credit. THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! I just added it as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your ExpandableListView is null. You want to move `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` to the top of the onCreate method. It might be causing troubles that you call `findViewById` before creating the Activity.